# command line oauth2 authoritation get permission from user

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, redirect

I want to write a program to download things from http://www.thingiverse.com/

I have difficulty to authenticate. Because it is a command line tool. The user have to click the allow button in browser to proceed (get redirect url and get the code). How to do that in python?

If I just do this:

```
import requests

#get access code
client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
redirect_uri = "http://wang-nima.github.io"

payload = {'client_id': client_id, 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
r = requests.get("https://www.thingiverse.com/login/oauth/authorize", params=payload)
print r.url
```

the url printed is the url you should press the allow button. not the redirect url. How to get the redirect url??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get consent from the user in an automated way because that would defeat the purpose of OAuth and would be a violation of the spec. What you could do is spawn a browser from your python environment, have the user login and consent in the browser and have him copy/paste the `code` back to your python script.